# How to figure out exactly where PHP CURL data and then parse is slowing down (PART 2)

Tags: php, curl

I have an PHP script that grabs an XML RSS feeds and then parses and formats it for display on a web page. For several years the HTML page in question would load instantly, now for that last month sometimes it loads almost instantly other times it can take almost 3 seconds to display. Thanks to the help in this post [How to figure out exactly where PHP CURL data and then parse is slowing down (part1 - answered)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72873166/edit) I was able to pinpoint that it is the CURL part of the script that is slowing down.
I updated my code from the part 1 to include a timeEnd - TimeStart calculation. The first time the script is run as I stated earlier, it takes 1-3 seconds for the CURL to complete. If I then refresh then browser the CURL takes in then range of .00002 seconds (even with a firefox shift/ctrl/r hard page refresh). After 30 seconds to a minute a refresh takes the extended time again. It obviously sounds like this part of the puzzle is related to it being cached, maybe on the server, since the browser full refresh doesn't slow it down. I'm not so concerned with the "cache" issue since what I really want it to speed up the initial load time (just mentioning it as it may give someone a clue to the larger problem).

The script is still working perfectly well/fast with other RSS URLs, just the Google one has the issue.

```
https://news.google.com/rss?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en **(URL WITH ISSUE)**
https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml **(FAST EVERY TIME)**

  $ch = curl_init();
 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);   
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: '.$domain));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  

  $data = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close($ch);

 
$tmE=microtime(true);
$elapsed = number_format($tmE - $tmS,9, ".", ",");
echo "<script>console.log('CURL ELAPSED TIME: . $elapsed ' );</script>";
```

Comment: _"just the Google one has the issue"_ - If it's the request that takes time, it sounds more like an issue with the service you're calling than your code (since you say it's only one single URL that has this issue). It could be that they have traffic limits, making it slower if you hammer their API (like you do when keep refreshing the page many times in a row)

Comment: When I load the google URL in my browser it always comes up 'instantly'. If it were hammering issue I would expect the reverse. The first load to be quick, and after hammering maybe a slower response. I feel like (and it is just a guess, based on nothing) it has something to do with SSL negotiation (since google really pushes SSL and this site wont load as plain http). I have CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST = FALSE to get the site to work. I tried several settings for CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION which didnt speed it up, but it was just random values from the man page

Comment: I also cant reproduce the slowness when I run CURL from a command line from my PC  (curl -w "@formtfile.txt" -o /dev/null -s 'news.google.com/rss?hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en'). Just slow when running from PHP on hosted server